# Jquery $.ajax function not returning data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, cs-cart

i'm trying to get some data as json from cs-cart API so in the browser when i call some data like this

```
user name : admin@example.com
password : j58O9J11085SBycaDKMY1C75k1998rup

http://demos.cs-cart.com/54bbdcef36bac/api/payments
```

it get the requested data but when i try call this data from $.ajax nothing happening

first i create an HTML page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>  

    <div id='#div1'></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery-2.1.1.min.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./GetData.js" ></script>
      </body>

</html>
```

and in the GetData.js

```
$(function(){
   $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://admin%40example.com:j58O9J11085SBycaDKMY1C75k1998rup@demos.cs-cart.com/54bbdcef36bac/api/payments',
            dataType: 'jsonp',

            success:function(result){
              console.log(result);
              $("#div1").html(result);  
            }
        });
        });
```

and no data is retrieved and there is no errores to so what should i do to retrieve the data from the json file thank for any help in advance.

UPDATE:

it give this error whene add s to http so it give `GET https://admin%40example.com:j58O9J11085SBycaDKMY1C75k1998rup@demos.cs-cart.…ayments?callback=jQuery211009486119472421706_1421614338422&_=1421614338423 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

why jquery add parameter

`?callback=jQuery211009486119472421706_1421614338422&_=1421614338423 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

to the url

UPDATE

it now get the json but in the response as .js file and when i try to console.log the data nothing happening

```
$(function(){
       $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'https://fadi40%example.com:j58O9J11085SBycaDKMY1C75k1998rup@demos.cs-cart.com/54bbdcef36bac/api/payments',
                dataType: 'jsonp',

                success:function(data){
                 console.log(data);

                }
            });
            });
```

Comment: real user name and password? wow!

Comment: it just a demo :D  user name and password

Comment: I think Same origin policy prevents queriyng another domain.

Comment: i try to debug this and it give this error any help on what to do
http://admin%40example.com:j58O9J11085SBycaDKMY1C75k1998rup@demos.cs-cart.c…/payments?callback=jQuery2110734999023610726_1421613108206&_=1421613108207

Comment: How do you know there are no errors?

Comment: i see the console on chrome and there is no error but i try different console and give me the error in the previous comment

Comment: `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` seems clear enough, and it adds the callback parameter because you told it to make a JSONP request. Go and read the Wikipedia page about JSONP if you want to know how it works (which you should do before trying to use it)

Comment: ok no problem but if i use just JSON it give me 
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://demos.cs-cart.com/54bbdcef36bac/api/payments. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
How can i get the json or how can i add the Access-Control-Allow-Origin to  in jquery